# Postgresql: Getting percentile and counting how many in each tile

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentile, quantile

I have generated following result set

```
"degree_easy","degree_hard","easy_percent","hard_percent"
1,5,0.166667,0.833333
1,5,0.166667,0.833333
1,6,0.142857,0.857143
1,8,0.111111,0.888889
```

above results set is generated from the following query:

```
select * from (
    select degree_one as degree_easy, 
        (degree_two + degree_three) as degree_hard,
        (degree_one::real/(degree_one::real + degree_two::real + degree_three::real)) 
            as easy_percent, 
        ((degree_two::real + degree_three::real)/(degree_one::real + degree_two::real +
            degree_three::real)) as hard_percent FROM recommendation_degree
    ) as dc 
where dc.degree_easy >= 1 and dc.degree_hard >= 1
order by dc.easy_percent ASC, dc.hard_percent ASC
```

Now what I am trying to do is calculate percentiles:

I am not sure which column from above make more sense to use but assuming I want to use degree_easy and degree_hard to calculate percentile or at least one of them How do I use `ntile` function in postgres to do this?

What is the best practice on doing following:

```
percentile, number_of_users
25, 4
50, 10
75, 20
99, 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ntile` can tell if you're in the bottom 25% of an ordered list.  But it does not support weights.  For `ntile` to work all groups have to be equal in size.

You could calculate weights using the `sum ... over` analytic function.  The running sum (sum of all rows with an equal or lower value than the current row) is:

```
sum(col1) over (order by col1)
```

The overall sum over the entire table is:

```
sum(col1) over ()
```

You can calculate the percentile by comparing the running sum to the overall sum.  A simplified example:

```
create table people (id serial, points int);
-- 3 people with 1 point, 2 people with 2 points, 1 person with 3 points
-- total 6 people and 10 points
insert into people (points) values (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (3);

select  *
,       case 
        when sum(points) over (order by points) > 0.75 * sum(points) over () then '100%'
        when sum(points) over (order by points) > 0.5 * sum(points) over () then '75%'
        when sum(points) over (order by points) > 0.25 * sum(points) over () then '50%'
        else '25%'
        end as Percentile
from    people
```

Which prints:

```
ID    POINTS  PERCENTILE
1     1       50%
2     1       50%
3     1       50%
4     2       75%
5     2       75%
6     3       100%
```

The people with 1 point have 3 points together, or 30% of the total.  That puts them in the 50% percentile.  The people with 2 points bring the total to 7, putting them in the top 75%.  The person with 3 points brings the total to 10, placing him in the top bracket.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/804a4/1/0)